# Dax query for multiple IF ELSE statements

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I need to display only that data which is going on currently. I have a table column with shift wise time. 
Shift 1 is always from 6 am to 2 pm. If it is 12pm data only till 12 pm should be displayed.
What can be the DAX query of it. I have come up with a logic but I am not very sure.

```
ShiftDump = if NOW() > (6,0,0) OR NOW() < (2,0,0) , then shift 1 else NOW()> (2,0,0) OR NOW() < (10,0,0) , then shift 2 else shift 3
```

How do I write a DAX Expression for it?

Answer (score 0):

This is DAX code:

```
ShiftDump = 
var h = HOUR(NOW())

return
SWITCH(
    TRUE();
    h >= 6 && h < 14; "Shift 1";
    ....
    "Shift 3"
)
```

Fill in the ... wth appropriate hour logic, and HOUR(NOW()) will giv a value between 0-23